# asynchron swift unit test getting called 3 times instead of 1

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, asynchronous, xctestcase

I've wrote a unit test for a asynchronous function which loads data via http request.

When I start the test its getting called 3 times instead of 1 time.

I tried to implement the unit tests like here:
https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2015/10/testing-asynchronous-code-in-swift/

My code looks like this:

```
func getWatches(completionHandler: @escaping ((result:Bool)) -> ()) {

   Some code ... 

   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in 

      Some code ...

      DispatchQueue.main.async(){
        completionHandler(true)
      }
   }).resume()
}



func testGetWatches() {
    let asyncExpectation = expectation(description: "longRunningFunction")

    WatchApiConnector.sharedInstance.getWatches() { (result) -> () in
        asyncExpectation.fulfill()
    }

    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 5) { error in

        XCTAssertEqual(WatchApiConnector.sharedInstance.watches.count,20,"20 expected")

    }
}
```

As result I get the following:

```
Test Suite 'WatchApiConnectorTests' passed at 2016-12-15 14:32:30.437.
     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.305 (0.306) seconds
Test Suite 'ChronextTests.xctest' passed at 2016-12-15 14:32:30.438.
     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.305 (0.307) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' passed at 2016-12-15 14:32:30.439.
     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.305 (0.309) seconds
```

So am I doing something wrong or is this the default behavior of async unit tests on iOS?

Comment: Well, it seems to be an issue with your project structure, rather then your code. Do you have 3 test targets in your project? Is this test class included in all 3 of them?

Comment: No I'm using one test target for the unit tests and one for the UI-tests. This test case also targets one test target.

Comment: Do you by chance run all your test targets when testing? Do they all contain one test case?

Comment: No I run only the test function not even the whole target. But also when I run all tests in my target its getting called 3 times

Comment: No solution on this one?